# Simple Numeric array questions

Tags: php, arrays

I am given this array

```
$names = ['John', 'James', 'Joe'];
```

And these questions

> - How would you assign the number of names in the array to a variable called $total?
> - How would you use the `$total` variable to assign the last name to a new variable called `$last`?

The answer for the first question I figured out is

```
$total = count($names);
```

to get the number of names in the names array. But when I go to the second question I am trying to use the `$total` variable to assign the last name to a new variable called last. I get this

```
$last = $total[2]
```

which is incorrect.
I get the error

> Trying to access array offset on value of type int

Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: $size = count($names)

Comment: I have already figured that part out as stated above with $total = count($names);

Comment: Hint: You want to use something related to `$total` as the index in the `$names` array.

Comment: I hope that's enough, because anything more would just do the work for you.

Comment: I feel like I am getting closer with $last = $names[$total] but obviously there is 3 names in the names array but there the indexes only go up to 2 which is the issue I am now facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider utilizing `$total` when finding the last name instead of hard coding `2`:

```php
<?php
$names = ['John', 'James', 'Joe'];
echo "\$names = " . PHP_EOL;
print_r($names);
$total = count($names);
echo "\$total = " . $total . PHP_EOL;
$last = $names[$total - 1];
echo "\$last = " . $last . PHP_EOL;
```

**Output:**

```
$names = 
Array
(
    [0] => John
    [1] => James
    [2] => Joe
)
$total = 3
$last = Joe
```

Comment: I did try the -1 but I put $last = $names[$total] - 1; instead but it makes total sense to have it inside the square brackets. Thank you so much!